# Is it possible to access Alfresco CIFS through Internet?

Tags: internet, cifs, alfresco

I know it's a security issue, but just by curiosity (I can't find a proper answer to that!), is it possible?

I defined cifs.broadcast=255.255.255.255 in the Alfresco configuration, but whatever I define, I can't access it.

I'm trying :

- \ip\alfresco
- \SERVER\alfresco  (with SERVER defined in hosts)
- \SERVERA\alfresco (with SERVER and SERVERA defined in hosts)

I'm sure CIFS is working because if I connect with a local machine, it works well, but not via Internet.

Thanks for your enlightenment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most sane ISPs will filter CIFS traffic. You'll need to set up a VPN to the server and tunnel the CIFS traffic over that.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea to do this without a VPN, but I question your statement about most ISPs filtering CIFS. I thought most ISPs don't filter anything. Maybe rate-limit, and maybe supply routers with default inbound FW rules, but I don't think they'd *block* things.

Comment: Well in my case, I've actually tested it, both with residential ISPs (CenturyLink, Comcast) and commercial ISPs (Time Warner Telecom, AT&T), and I've never been able to pass CIFS traffic successfully.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I was expecting. Thank you for it! :)